# present a specific VC when local notification is tapped Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I tried to follow various solutions to the same problem in other posts but none seems to be applicable to my code.
I merged an alarm into my app and my goal is to get to `NewMapViewController`on user tapping on alarm local notification and call `checkAlerts2()` function which is not normally called when going to that VC via the app menu.
Thank you for you help as usual.
This is my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AlarmApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    let alarmScheduler: AlarmSchedulerDelegate = Scheduler()
    var alarmModel: Alarms = Alarms()


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        var error: NSError?
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch let error1 as NSError{
            error = error1
            print("could not set session. err:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch let error1 as NSError{
            error = error1
            print("could not active session. err:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        window?.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }

    //receive local notification when app in foreground
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {

        //show an alert window
        let storageController = UIAlertController(title: "Check route for alerts?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        var isSnooze: Bool = false
        var soundName: String = ""
        var routeName: String = ""
        var index: Int = -1
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            isSnooze = userInfo["snooze"] as! Bool
            soundName = userInfo["soundName"] as! String
            routeName = userInfo["routeName"] as! String
            index = userInfo["index"] as! Int
        }

        playSound(soundName)
        //schedule notification for snooze
        if isSnooze {
            let snoozeOption = UIAlertAction(title: "Snooze", style: .default) {
                (action:UIAlertAction)->Void in self.audioPlayer?.stop()
                self.alarmScheduler.setNotificationForSnooze(snoozeMinute: 9, soundName: soundName, routeName: routeName, index: index)
            }
            storageController.addAction(snoozeOption)
        }
        let stopOption = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
            (action:UIAlertAction)->Void in self.audioPlayer?.stop()
            AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
            self.alarmModel = Alarms()
            self.alarmModel.alarms[index].onSnooze = false
            //change UI
            var mainVC = self.window?.visibleViewController as? MainAlarmViewController
//            var mainVC = self.window?.visibleViewController as? NewMapViewController
            if mainVC == nil {
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Alarm") as? MainAlarmViewController
//                mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Alarm") as? NewMapViewController
            }
            mainVC!.changeSwitchButtonState(index: index)
//            MainAlarmViewController?.changeSwitchButtonState(index: index)
        }

        storageController.addAction(stopOption)
        window?.visibleViewController?.navigationController?.present(storageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //snooze notification handler when app in background
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, for notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        var index: Int = -1
        var soundName: String = ""
        var routeName: String = ""
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            soundName = userInfo["soundName"] as! String
            routeName = userInfo["routeName"] as!String
            index = userInfo["index"] as! Int
        }
        self.alarmModel = Alarms()
        self.alarmModel.alarms[index].onSnooze = false
        if identifier == Id.snoozeIdentifier {
            alarmScheduler.setNotificationForSnooze(snoozeMinute: 9, soundName: soundName, routeName: routeName,  index: index)
            self.alarmModel.alarms[index].onSnooze = true
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    //AlarmApplicationDelegate protocol
    func playSound(_ soundName: String) {

        //vibrate phone first
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        //set vibrate callback
        AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate),nil,
                                              nil,
                                              { (_:SystemSoundID, _:UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Void in
                                                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        },
                                              nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: "mp3")!)

        var error: NSError?

        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            audioPlayer = nil
        }

        if let err = error {
            print("audioPlayer error \(err.localizedDescription)")
            return
        } else {
            audioPlayer!.delegate = self
            audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        }

        //negative number means loop infinity
        audioPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer!.play()
    }

    //AVAudioPlayerDelegate protocol
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

    }

    func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, error: Error?) {

    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        //        audioPlayer?.play()
        alarmScheduler.checkNotification()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
         */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "fix-it mapView")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: try a dummy project. Setup a local notification. Fire it and then upon tapping it and getting its callback try opening a viewcontroller. Your current code has too much noise which are unrelated...

Comment: Additionally since iOS10 `UILocalNotification` has been deprecated. You should use `UserNotifications` instead. see [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250)

Comment: @Honey. I know, and I get warnings for that depreciated UILocalNotification, but the strange part is that I don't get them when I open the project that this code comes from. I did implement an alarm into my app, that's what it is, but If I open the alarm project compiler doesn't give me this warnings.